# MSSQL DB Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, migration

I am involved in a MSSQL DB migration activity from version MSSQL 2005 to MSSQL 2012. Since the number of databases are huge and there are lots of customization or property changes were done, I want a way to take a output of all database properties which are not default values. so that i can create a database with same property value and import the database from source database.

I can find some scripts which will provide all properties of a DB but its difficult to identify the properties which are not default. Can some one help on this.

Just for information, I am a middleware guy presently supporting the DB migration activity due to volume of the work.

Comment: How do you want to migrate? If you backup and restore db, options will be in the backup. Am I missing something? What kind of options?

Comment: Actually based on my KT what I am doing is, I will create a DB with same naming convention, properties etc in destination server. Then I will export the DB in Source server and import it in destination server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 supports upgrade from only the following versions: SQL 2005 SP4 or SQL 2008 SP2 or SQL 2008 R2 SP1.